# Swift: how to reload a table with navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, uinavigationcontroller

Im a beginner so please be friendly explaining, thanks.

So basically each time i tap on a cell and then tap back how can i fully reload the table again.

I tried adding `tableView.reloadData()` in viewDidAppear and `viewWillAppear`, It didn't work and tried adding `parseQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`

so i'm going to explain what i am trying to do exactly

on parse I have a bool and basically if that is false i display false data and if its true I don't display anything and once I tap on that cell i change the bool to true and when I tap on back I want it to reload the table so it will check again if the bool is true or false.

***UPDATED***

I have moved the fetching into `viewWillApear` and the results are closer to what i want. Now when i tap on any of the cells the last one gets removed which is not how it should be. The one i tapped that one should get removed from the list.

1. **Item 1**
2. **Item 2**
3. **Item 3**
4. **Item 4**

When i tap on Item 1 logically Item 1 should get removed because in parse the bool will be set to false and once set to false it should not be displayed but what happens is Item 4 gets removed and when i relaunch the app i see Item 1 is removed and the rest are there as they should be.

```
     class recentTableViewController: UITableViewController {

     var tdyName = [String]()
     var dataparse: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

     override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)

      self.tdyName.removeAll()

      let parseQuery = PFQuery(className: "request")
         parseQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
             if let objects = objects {

            for object in objects {
                if object["reqRead"] as! Bool == false {    
                print("reqs not read")

                    self.tdyName.append(object["reqName"] as! String)
                    self.dataparse.addObject(object)

                } else {

                 print("req read")
                }
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }


}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    return tdyName.count 
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("recentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! recentTableViewCell

    let backgroundQueue = NSOperationQueue()
    backgroundQueue.addOperationWithBlock(){

        let cellDataParse: PFObject = self.dataparse.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock(){

            myCell.recentName.text = cellDataParse.objectForKey("reqName")! as? String

        }

    }
    return myCell
}
}
```

I do change it to true in different view but then when i come back to this i dont see any changes unless i go back to main view and come back here so it will reload completely and i see changes.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  If you only change the bool on Parse, you would need to read it from Parse to know the new value.  `viewDidLoad` has the query but won't be called just by returning to the view.  When you say `viewWillAppear` didn't work, were you re-doing the query from there?

Comment: @PhillipMills I have updated the codes and explained more if that will help

Comment: Your update talks about the wrong thing being removed but I don't see any code that deals with selecting something for removal.

Comment: @PhillipMills Basically there is a tableView with cells and once you tap on a cell it takes you to a different `viewController` where there is two buttons which is accept and reject, once any of the buttons are tapped the bool value becomes false then you will go back to the tableView and there the last item in the tableView gets removed

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts to get your started:

**Background Threads**

You have a couple of tasks going in the background (which can be a good thing), but once you get your results, you need to update any UI elements on the main thread.  There are several ways to do this, but something like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
  tableview.reloadData()
}
```

Also, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you call a background thread again, so the code  continues (while the thread runs) and your `cell` is returning initialized, but the recentName.txt is probably not what you expect.

**TableViews**

You need to have a local collection (usually an `Array`) to hold the data you want to display in the tableView.  Currently you are returning `tdyName.count` for the number of rows, so usually you will build your cells from the same source: `tdyName` (again: not always, but in most simple cases this is the case).  If `tdyName` can be a true or false value, it needs to be saved somewhere locally so you can access it (after it's retrieved/written to the database).  You are storing the results of the true/false in a separate `Array` called dataparse.  While not technically incorrect, it has a high probably of getting out of sync with tdyName.

Recommendation:  Consider creating a struct that holds holds both values, then your array contains those structs instead, like this:

```
struct Tdy {     //of course use a better name for this
   let name: String
   var readReqs = false
}
```

When you read the data from the database you create an instance of Tdy and assign that to the data array, so your data array definition would look like this.

```
var dataArray = [Tdy]()
```

...then change numberOfRowsInSection to

```
return dataArray.count
```

this will still show ALL values.  If you only want false records to show, you would filter them out.  Something like this:

```
return dataArray.filter() { $0.readReqs == false }
```

Finally, you should remove the parse call in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and populate your labels in your cell from 'dataArray[indexPath.row]' like this:

```
myCell.recentName.text = dataArray[indexPath.row]
```

This may not fix all your issues with changing data, but until the underpinnings are right, you will probably pull your hair out.  Once you have the right struct

**TIP:** The code block that is being called in `viewDidLoad` should really be moved to a function, and call that function from `viewDidLoad`.  This wont immediately change functionality, but it is clearer, and as your app(s) grows, you will want to be able to re-use code as much as possible - extracting this code will allow it to be called from anywhere (in scope).

This is a lot to chew on, so let me know if you need further help.  If you take a crack at it, repost your code and we'll help you further!

Comment: This is vey helpful in future, thank you so much, but now i am facing a different problem and i have updated the codes to what i am trying to do please check and see if you know any way around or solution thanks.

Comment: One month passed and i didn't get any solutions. I guess they do get out of sync because when i `print` them and check them in log its correct but what shows me is wrong and i don't know how to create a `Struct` connected to Database. I would appreciate it if you could help me.